# Javascript Dispatch mouse events does not does not propagate to target children

Tags: javascript

I'm working on layers that are over others and a way to send events.
The dispatch event works but does not is propagated to inner elements like a button.

The jsfiddle shows the problem.

I have a layer and inside it two other absolutely positioned. I want to send events from top displayed layer to last 'brother' layer. It works, as you can see at log, but the button is not reached by the event propagation.

It seems that this event does not propagate as normal events...

Maybe I can't make what I want....

```
 <div id="top" style="width: 100%; height:100%;">                 
    <div id="UpperLayer2" style="width: 100%; height:100%;border: 1px solid green; margin: 50px; position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;">
        <input type="button" value="> > >" onclick="show()">
    </div>
    <div id="DownLayer" style="width: 100%; height:100%;border: 1px solid blue;margin: 0px;position: absolute; top: 0;left: 0px;">
        <input type="button" value="button at down layer" onclick="show()">
    </div>                        
</div>


<script>
    function show () {alert("yes");}

    document.getElementById("top")
        .addEventListener("mousedown", rise_event_to_upper, true);    
    document.getElementById("UpperLayer2")
        .addEventListener("click", doSomethingUpper2, true);
    document.getElementById("DownLayer")
        .addEventListener("click", doSomethingDown, true);

    function rise_event_to_upper(e) {
        console.log("define & dispatch: "+e.eventPhase);
        var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
            bubbles: false,
            cancelable: true,
            view: window,
        });
        document.getElementById("UpperLayer2").dispatchEvent(evt);      
    }
    function doSomethingDown(e) {  
        console.log ("capture down: "+e.eventPhase);
    }
    function doSomethingUpper(e) {                 
        console.log ("capture upper: "+e.eventPhase);
    }
    function doSomethingUpper2(e) {                 
        console.log ("capture upper2: "+e.eventPhase);    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that confuse the order of your elements.
Add to #DownLayer following style:

```
background-color: blue;
```

And you should look like:

```
<div id="DownLayer" style="width: 100%; height:100%;border: 1px solid blue;margin: 0px;position: absolute; top: 0;left: 0px; background-color: blue;">
    <input type="button" value="button at down layer" onclick="show()">
</div>
```

As you can see you can not see the button that is within the div #UpperLayer therefore you can never click on it.

In addition DownLayer is who is in front and behind UpperLayer is Who

That is exactly what we want to do?

Comment: NO. I want the dispatched event can arrive to the button but it is not propagated .... It stops at the level of container div ....